# разделение ленты новостей по дням, django шаблонизатор

Tags: django

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

возможно ли разделить контент на блоки, которые будут выводится как на картинке, только с возможностями шаблонизатора, без js...[возможно используя вот эту фичу](https://rtfm.co.ua/django-book-vtoroe-predstavlenie-dinamicheskij-kontent/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Для этой цели есть стандартный тег [regroup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/templates/builtins/#regroup):

```
{% regroup news by pub_date as date_groups %}

<ul>
{% for group in date_groups %}
    <li>{{ group.grouper }}
    <ul>
        {% for post in group.list %}
          <li>{{ post.title }}</li>
        {% endfor %}
    </ul>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```